# Having trouble adding local image using HTML

Tags: html, image

I have an image on my computer that I'm trying to add to my HTML by using
img src="myheadshot.jpeg" (arrows included in VS Code), but nothing shows up. I've been able to add images from Google using the image address, but I can't seem to find a solution to the local image issue.

I'm just beginning my coding journey, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where is your image located relative to your HTML file? The reference is relative to the HTML file. If you go with `src="myheadshot.jpeg"`, it means that it looks for the image in the *same folder*. If it's not in the same folder as the HTML file, you'll need to specify the relative path. Additionally note that if you're uploading to an actual website, you'll need to upload the image as well -- it needs to be on the same machine that is serving the content.

Comment: Thank you! My image was in a different folder than my HTML file, but I'm glad to know I can also specify the path now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code and image are saved in the same file or location on your computer. (e.g. The code and image are both saved on the desktop or in a file on the desktop.)

Also, maybe try this:

```
src="myheadshot.jpg"
```

Not really a difference, but it works for me!

Comment: Thank you for you help! The file location was the issue. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @yoyocharlie No problem, good luck with your project!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I wish you success in this journey that you have just started.

For now, you can paste the image into your IDE and use the extension with the name there.`enter code here`

Example:

Let the name in the file be bg.jpg.

```
<img src="bg.jpg" >
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I didn't know it wasn't supposed to be like this :)

Comment: So you can fix that by typing the text into your answer. Otherwise your answer will soon be deleted.